# Can a TaskCanceledException mean a Deadlock has occurred?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am working on making one of our applications async, and now my HttpClient is timing out (I get a `TaskCanceledException`) when I call SendAsync.  Here is the code that's timing out:

```
            response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

From what I understand, `ConfigureAwait(false)` means that I can't deadlock this task.  I am awaiting for this all the way up(or down) the stack.

When I make the same request in postman it takes will under a second.  The timeout for my HttpClient is 2 minutes.  Could there be something else going on?

Also, because I am getting a `TaskCanceledException` does that mean that my Tasks are not deadlocked?

**Update**

Thanks for the answer @Servy, I have managed to get around my problem by changing the above code to:

```
            response = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
                .ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

So if I don't await it, everything works properly.  Does this mean that it is most likely a deadlock somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

> From what I understand, `ConfigureAwait(false)` means that I can't deadlock this task.

That's not true.  You get a deadlock anytime you're synchronously waiting on your synchronization context on an asynchronous operation that's trying to execute a continuation on that same synchronization context.  That *this one* continuation isn't trying to use the synchronization context doesn't meant that there isn't some other continuation somewhere else that is.  So while we know that this one `await` isn't what's *causing* the deadlock, it doesn't mean there isn't one.

> I am awaiting for this all the way up(or down) the stack.

If this is true, and there is nothing synchronously blocking the synchronization context then *that* would mean you don't have a deadlock in your code.  (Or at least, not this common source of a deadlock.)

> When I make the same request in postman it takes will under a second. The timeout for my HttpClient is 2 minutes. Could there be something else going on?

Sure.  A firewall could be getting in the way, your network cord could have come unplugged, the other site could be offline, or intentionally ignoring your requests for some reason.

> Also, because I am getting a TaskCanceledException does that mean that my Tasks are not deadlocked?

It doesn't really tell you either way.  If the specific operation that's trying to schedule a continuation on a blocked synchronization context also has a cancellation token that results in it timing out after a while, then it'd deadlock until it was cancelled.  But there are of course any number of things that could result in a `Task` being cancelled without there being a deadlock.